# Connecting a native iOS app to backend and database

Tags: database, web-services, ios, mobile

I have a good amount of experience working with objective-C and making iOS apps that work locally and with BaaS providers (Parse.com). However, I'd like to take my mobile development to the next level and I'd like tips on the order in which to do things and tips on which services/technologies to use.

So, I need a database, and a place to host my database. I've used Amazon AWS for some things, and I can easily set up a mySQL DB on an EC2 instance there. Alternatively, I've heard that GAE is very useful.

I don't really know if I have to write any back-end code. It seems to me that objective-C can take the place of my back-end code. Is that secure? Should I be making an entire service that is simply called from the iPhone?

So, I know that it's a loaded question, and it may require a few different opinions to really round out a good answer. Sorry about that. But, assuming that I am proficient enough with Obj-C to make anything happen client side, and that I'm sentient enough to learn other languages that I might not know and follow tutorials and examples online - What are the steps (and the best technologies/services at each step) to making a native iOS app that does not use a BaaS provider like Parse.com or Stackmob.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason to store data remote when it's just a one client offline app?

But to answer your question (not sure if I understand it correctly):
In most cases you gonna build a layer (e.g. a webservice) between your mobile app and your database. The webservice is responsible for data manipulation (access the database and offers through an API just these methods/data which are absolutely needed, handles multi user concurrent database access and so on), provides security mechanisms (authentication, authorization), abstraction of concerns, implements business rules/logic, ...

And I'm sure you will write back-end code. Depending on you project you might have the requirement to provide access to other developers...at this point at least you must have an API for regulated access!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was just saying I knew how to make a one client offline app so that I wasn't answered with people pointing me towards obj-c tutorials. Last question, what's the difference between the web service and the backend code? Or does the back-end code just exist within the web service?